# How to pass values into database using AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to pass certain values into a database using AJAX.  With the current script I have, the PHP checks for the submit button post and processes the form.  It's a standard form entry into a database, but that's not the issue, I have elements in my form that aren't form values, it's text within a div that I'm trying to pass into the database using AJAX and I'm not entirely sure how to go about doing this.  I don't need help with the PHP, which is why I'm not posting it, I just need help doing the AJAX to get the selected values and passing them into the database.

```
var Alerts = {
        apu: [["APU Power Fail", "APU[1]"], ["APU Power Fault", "APU[2]"], ["APU Generator Fail", "APU[3]"], ["APU High Oil Temperature", "APU[4]"], ["APU Hot Start", "APU[5]"], ["APU Loss Overspeed Protection", "APU[6]"], ["APU Starter Engaged", "APU[7]"], ["APU Fire", "APU[8]"], ["APU Fails Bite Check", "APU[9]"], ["APU Door Fails to Open", "APU[10]"], ["APU No Flame", "APU[11]"], ["Left Fire Bottle Discharge", "APU[12]"]],

        avionics: [["ADS 1 Fail", "AVIONICS[1]"], ["ADS 2 Fail", "AVIONICS[2]"], ["ADS 3 Fail", "AVIONICS[3]"], ["AP 1 Fail", "AVIONICS[4]"], ["AP 2 Fail", "AVIONICS[5]"], ["Autopilots Fail", "AVIONICS[6]"], ["Baroset 1 Fail", "AVIONICS[7]"], ["Baroset 2 Fail", "AVIONICS[8]"], ["Baroset 3 Fail", "AVIONICS[9]"], ["CCD 1 Fail", "AVIONICS[10]"], ["CCD  2 Fail", "AVIONICS[11]"], ["Heading Comparison Monitor", "AVIONICS[12]"], ["Heading and Roll Comparison Monitor", "AVIONICS[13]"], ["Display Controller 1 Fail", "AVIONICS[14]"], ["Display Controller 2 Fail", "AVIONICS[15]"], ["IRS 1 Fail", "AVIONICS[16]"], ["IRS 2 Fail", "AVIONICS[17]"], ["IRS 3 Fail", "AVIONICS[18]"], ["Glideslope Antenna Fail", "AVIONICS[19]"], ["MAU 1A Fail", "AVIONICS[20]"], ["MAU 1B Fail", "AVIONICS[21]"], ["MAU 2A Fail", "AVIONICS[22]"], ["MAU 2B Fail", "AVIONICS[23]"], ["MAU 3A Fail", "AVIONICS[24]"], ["MAU 3B Fail", "AVIONICS[25]"], ["MRC 1 Fail", "AVIONICS[26]"], ["MRC 2 Fail", "AVIONICS[27]"], ["GPS Degrade", "AVIONICS[28]"], ["GPS #1 Fail", "AVIONICS[28]"], ["GPS #2 Fail", "AVIONICS[30]"], ["Display Unit 1 Fail", "AVIONICS[31]"], ["Display Unit 2 Fail", "AVIONICS[32]"], ["Display Unit 3 Fail", "AVIONICS[33]"], ["Display Unit 4 Fail", "AVIONICS[34]"], ["GPS - Unable RNP", "AVIONICS[35]"]]
    }
    var description, breaker;
    for(var key in Alerts){
        var system = key.toUpperCase();
        $("#systems").append("<div class='systems' id='" +key +"'><div class='select_box'></div><h2>" +system +"</h2></div>");
    }
    $("#systems").on("click", ".systems", function(){
        $("#malfunctions").children().remove();
        $(this).find(".select_box").each(function(){
            $(".selected").removeClass("selected");
            $(this).addClass("selected");
        })
        $.each(Alerts[this.id], function(ind,item){
            description = item[0];
            breaker = item[1];
            $("#malfunctions").append("<div class='systems'><div class='select_box'></div><p data-id='" +description +"'>" +description +"</p></div>");
        })
    })
    $("#malfunctions").on("click", ".systems", function(){
        $(this).find(".select_box").each(function(){
            if($(this).hasClass("selected")){
                $(this).removeClass("selected");
            }
            else{
                $(this).addClass("selected");
                var text = $(this).closest(".systems").text();
            }
        })
    })
```

The divs on the right with the red box showing are the selected items that I want to pass into the database.
[image]

Comment: Where is your PHP? I also don't see any AJAX here.

Comment: That's what I'm asking, how do I use AJAX to pass this script to put the data into the database.

Comment: This explains it. http://learn.jquery.com/ajax/. Come up with something and we can help you from there with specific questions.

Comment: This will also be helpful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9534395/jquery-ajax-call-to-a-database-query

Comment: Will do thanks for the resources.  Hopefully I can post something more tomorrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to loop through your elements and set its text into an array then you can pass the data via an object and handle it easily via PHP POST as an array of values:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  var data_values = [];

  $("#malfunctions > .selected").each(function(index, el) {
     data_values[index] = el.innerText;
  });

  $.ajax({
     url: '/path/to/file',
     type: 'POST',
     dataType: 'json',
     data: {myData: data_values}
  })
});
```

Comment: FIX: changed `{myData: data}` the correct value is `{myData: data_values}`

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this :

```
...

var data = '';
$('.selected').each(function(){
    data += $(this).parent().children('p').attr('data-id') + ',';
})
```

And then ...

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "some.php",
    data: { values: data }
})
.done(function( msg ) {

});
```

This is just the manner, not a code to copy and paste ;)